# Cropping, scaling and centering a bitmap

Tags: android, image, crop

I have a picture in a file in portrait mode and I want to use as wallpaper.
this is easy so far.
but the picture doesn't have same proportions as my device screen does. so there is a blank part of the screen at the bottom.
I am really terrible working with graphics.
How can I scale my Bitmap to fit my screen? It doesn't matter if I loose information as long as the seen part is centered.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the 9patch tool

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

You can use this tool to set which areas you want to stretch and which to keep the same.

Comment: Your not coding. It's a tool that comes in the android-sdk/tools. Did you check out the link?

Comment: yes, that is why I ask for code. because I don't want to do it with just one file.
I need code to enable my application to do it.

Comment: Ahh gotya. Then your going to have to take a look at
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html
Haven't used this before, but you should be able to dig up some examples somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

First you get your image in a `Bitmap` with [public static Bitmap decodeResource (Resources res, int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29) (if the image is an app resource, if not, you could use [public static Bitmap decodeFile (String pathName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) to read a file)

Then pass that Bitmap as a parameter to the next method with the rectangle you want to crop from the `Bitmap` and you will have a cropped Bitmap as a result:

[public static Bitmap createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources() , R.drawable.your_image );
Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, 400, 800);
```

Is this what you need?